# Regular Expression for the Pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner to Regular Expression and  trying to search for a specific pattern of numbers.
the below data is embedded in xml format.

```
<Tag Name="DUT_1_PC" TagType="Base" DataType="Power" Constant="false" ExternalAccess="Read/Write">
<Data Format="xx">
<![CDATA[[10247,20000,1705,0,16384,16384,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[[0,0,0],[1965615,2000,2000],[1952824,50000,0],[0,10000,0],[1928064,500,0
        ],[1928064,10000,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],4,1705,[24779,24760,24760,24760,24780,24740,24760,24780,24760,24800,24740
        ,24740,24740,24780,24740,24740,24800,24780,24760,24760,24740,24780,24760,24760,24740,24740,24780,24760
        ,24740,24740,24779,24779,24760,24819,24780,24740,24759,24780,24760,24740,24720,24780,24780,24760,24760
        ,24740,24779,24780,24740,24760,24820,24780,24740,24780,24760,24780,24780,24760,24781,24719,24779,24800
        ,24780,24780,24760,24760,24799,24780,24780,24780,24739,24780,24780,24740,24779,24741,24780,24780,24760
        ,24740,24740,24720,24740,24780,24740,24720,24760,24800,24740,24760,24760,24800,24740,24780,24760,24740,24760,24740,24740,24740,24780,24760,24780,24739,24761,24760,24800,24780,24740,24719,24739,24760,24760]]]]
```

The requirement is to extract the data(innermost list). Here in the example, the data starting from 24779 to 24760.
Note: Every time the data may not start from "24".
Hence I am planning to extract by the following logic:
If the Tag Name(In this case:DUT_1_PC) has valid data  other than Zero and count of valid data is more than 100 separated by commas then extract that list and its tag name(DUT_1_PC).

I am unable to extract the required data.

re.findall(r'\d+(?:[\d,.]*\d)')
This Regular expression extracts all the list data which doesn't suffice my requirement.

Could anybody help me to figure out the Regular expression to extract the  required data and its tag?

Comment: Why don't you use an XML parser?

Comment: If you know pandas already you could check https://pypi.org/project/pandas-read-xml/ Then it's easy to manipulate the data in pandas

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you mean by *innermost list*.  In your example, `[0,0,0]` is more deeply nested than the list you mentioned.  Assuming you mean the *last list*, then `re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)]*]]>$', DATA, re.MULTILINE)` (find all [...] lists that end with "]]>") will find all of those.

However as others mentioned, it is much better to use an XML parser:

```
DATA = """
<Outer>
<Tag Name="DUT_1_PC" TagType="Base" DataType="Power" Constant="false" ExternalAccess="Read/Write">
<Data Format="xx">
<![CDATA[[10247,20000,1705,0,16384,16384,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[[0,0,0],[1965615,2000,2000],[1952824,50000,0],[0,10000,0],[1928064,500,0
        ],[1928064,10000,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],4,1705,[24779,24760,24760,24760,24780,24740,24760,24780,24760,24800,24740
        ,24740,24740,24780,24740,24740,24800,24780,24760,24760,24740,24780,24760,24760,24740,24740,24780,24760
        ,24740,24740,24779,24779,24760,24819,24780,24740,24759,24780,24760,24740,24720,24780,24780,24760,24760
        ,24740,24779,24780,24740,24760,24820,24780,24740,24780,24760,24780,24780,24760,24781,24719,24779,24800
        ,24780,24780,24760,24760,24799,24780,24780,24780,24739,24780,24780,24740,24779,24741,24780,24780,24760
        ,24740,24740,24720,24740,24780,24740,24720,24760,24800,24740,24760,24760,24800,24740,24780,24760,24740,24760,24740,24740,24740,24780,24760,24780,24739,24761,24760,24800,24780,24740,24719,24739,24760,24760]]]]>
</Data>
</Tag> 
</Outer>     
"""

import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Find [...] list at end of string
pattern = re.compile(r'\[([^]]*)]+$', re.MULTILINE)
parsed = ET.fromstring(DATA)
for tag in parsed.findall('Tag'):
    if tag.attrib.get('Name') == 'DUT_1_PC':
        print(re.findall(pattern, tag.find('Data').text))
```